# How to add javascript attribute in xslt file in sitecore

Tags: javascript, xslt, sitecore, sitecore6

I have added attribute in asp.net hyperlink server control in sitecore as per given below:

```
hlFile.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert(website name" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["websitename"].ToString() + ")");
```

which is fine but now I have to do the same work in .xslt file and code is given below:

```
<sc:link field="Link Button" select="$thisItem">
  <sc:text field="website name" select="$thisItem"/>
</sc:link>
```

Anybody suggest me how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
<xsl:attribute name="onclick">foobar</xsl:attribute>
```

But I remember that it was not possible to do this with sc:link - in the worst case you have to build up the link manually...

```
<a href="{sc:path($thisItem)}">
   <xsl:attribute name="onclick">Foobar</xsl:attribute>
...
```

have Fun!!
:)